# manually coloring point geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im doing plotting cluster using ggplot. I'd like to custom the color for cluster 0, but somehow it didnt work.

```
Hasil<-Result$cluster
latitude<-datafile$latitude
longitude<-datafile$longitude
stdb<-data.frame(latitude,longitude,Hasil)

plotpeta<- function(stdb){
#read shape file
map<- readOGR(dsn="D:/peta", layer="indo_districts")
map@data$id <- rownames(map@data)

#convert to dataframe
maps<-fortify(map)
mergemap <- join(maps, map@data, by="id")
ggplot(mergemap) + aes(long,lat, group=group) +
  geom_polygon(data=map, aes(long, lat, group=group), color="grey") + 
  geom_path(data=map, color="white")+
  geom_polygon(data=mergemap, aes(long,lat))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_point(data=stdb, aes(longitude,latitude,group=1), color="white", size=2) +
  geom_point(data=stdb, aes(longitude,latitude, group=1, color=factor(Hasil)), size=2) +
  ylab("Longitude") + xlab("Latitude") +
  scale_color_hue(name="Hasil", l=40, c=40) +
  guides(col=guide_legend(ncol=10, byrow = TRUE, override.aes =list(size=3))) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=10, byrow=TRUE), size=1)+
  coord_equal()

}
```

so that the cluster plotting turns out like this

[image: the cluster 0 in the picture has color that is similar to cluster 1,2]

I want to differ the cluster 0 because it's noise.
Any suggestion about how to make it white?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you set a manual palette by creating a concatenated list:

You might want to use `scale_color_manual` to apply colors as you see appropriate.

You can use `values=` argument to assign colors to the appropriate level of a categorical variable, or a number if you have specific discrete numbers or to a name of a series.

```
  scale_colour_manual( values = c("0" = "white","1" = "blue","7" = "orange")) +
```

Make sure that this line of code directly follows the geom_point describing your data points.

If you want to keep a bunch of values equal to "blue, just define all of them in a concatenated list within the values list:

```
previous color.., c("1", "2", "3", "4") = "blue" , ...other colors
```

if you are explicit, account for all possible outcomes and are meticulous with grammar this should work.